# Multi-cluster Kubernetes with percentage traffic cross cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, cloudflare, azure-aks

Right now, i have production infrastucture in google cloud GKE. I am planning to migrate it to azure AKS.

I am being confused of strategy how to do traffic percentage cross different cluster while i am migrating from GKE to AKS (zero downtime).

Example,

In google cloud, i use Cloudflare + GCLB and NEG (network endpoint groups) as backend-service and in azure, i use Application Gateway Ingress Controller (AGIC).

A microservice we call XYZ service is deployed inside GKE and AKS. I can say that i can visit the xyz.domain.tld and got expected response.

How do i implement percentage traffic such as 10% traffic will go to AKS and the 90% left stay in GKE ?

Should i implement istio in my current production environment ? or does Cloudflare have a feature for percentage traffic such as 90% will go to GKE IP Address and 10% will go to AKS IP Address ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with [**Cloudflare's Workers**](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/), which is a serverless application platform running on Cloudflare’s global cloud network.

For **A/B testing scenario** take a look at [this example](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/ab-testing) in the official Cloudflare Workers docs:

> A/B testing Set up an A/B test by controlling what response is served
> based on cookies.
>
> ```
> function handleRequest(request) {
>   const NAME = "experiment-0"
>
>   // The Responses below are placeholders. You can set up a custom path for each test (e.g. /control/somepath ).
>   const TEST_RESPONSE = new Response("Test group") // e.g. await fetch("/test/sompath", request)
>   const CONTROL_RESPONSE = new Response("Control group") // e.g. await fetch("/control/sompath", request)
>
>   // Determine which group this requester is in.
>   const cookie = request.headers.get("cookie")
>   if (cookie && cookie.includes(`${NAME}=control`)) {
>     return CONTROL_RESPONSE
>   }
>   else if (cookie && cookie.includes(`${NAME}=test`)) {
>     return TEST_RESPONSE
>   }
>   else {
>     // If there is no cookie, this is a new client. Choose a group and set the cookie.
>     const group = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "test" : "control" // 50/50 split
>     const response = group === "control" ? CONTROL_RESPONSE : TEST_RESPONSE
>     response.headers.append("Set-Cookie", `${NAME}=${group}; path=/`)
>
>     return response
>   }
> }
>
> addEventListener("fetch", event => {
>   event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
> })
> ```

Comment: is there a feature or stack that can apply percentage traffic based on DNS IP Address ? Example, mydomain.tld have 3 ip address (A,B, and C) but i can configure 90% to IP A and B, and 10% left to IP C ?

Comment: well, nothing that I heard about, but if your domain is managed on cloudflare, I guess you can try and adjust the above script also to a scenario where your traffic is distributed among mentioned 3 ip addresses behind yourdomain.tld